# Redirect script not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: redirect

I have a script I'm using to redirect users to a "thank you" page after they submit a form. The redirect is working on all the browsers I've tested so far except Internet Explorer (IE9). 
Here's the script:

```
<script>
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( 'form.widget_wysija' ).submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(function() {
                var msg = $( '.wysija-msg' );
                if( msg.text() !== '' ){
                    window.location.replace( 'http://your_thank_you_page_url' );
                }
            }, 3000);
        });
    });
})(window.jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I used: `window.location.href="your_thank_you_page_url";`